# How can I get this gradient effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, shapes, illustration, effects

I tried to copy and paste forward each one of the hexagon strokes with a gradient, but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: If any of the below answers have answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

There are a few ways to create the gradient effect, but this is how I would do it...

Create the hexagon shape out of 6 triangles:

[image]

Then apply different gradients to each triangle:

[image]

Finally mask parts of the triangle gradients with hexagons (solid for the middle, strokes for the others):

[image]

Comment: the individual hexagons also seem to have some embossing - intentional or as a result of unsharpness.

Answer (score 9):

This will give you a flat color version:

- Create one hexagon
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies it to clipboard
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> duplicates the shape (aka. Paste in Place)
- scale up either one of these 2 hexagons until it looks right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects both shapes
- Go to 'Object → Blend → Blend Options' and choose 10 Specified Steps (or as many as you want in between)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> makes the blend
- then play with the Stroke Weight and/or adjust each of the hexagons' size

[image]

If you're looking for actual gradients to be applied for each of the 6 resulting 'sections':

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects all
- Go to 'Object → Expand → OK'
- Go to 'Object → Path → Outline Stroke'
- Reduce the shape to a single triangle, duplicate, rotate, reposition.

[image]